# How is a WebSocket handshake implemented in PHP?

Tags: php, websocket

I am trying to write a piece of code which will generate the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` value for a web socket connection. What I gather from resources online (i.e. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers)) is that you:

1. Concatenate the string that the client sent you in `Sec-WebSocket-Key` onto the GUID (`258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11`);
2. Take the SHA-1 hash of the result of this concatenation;
3. Convert the result of that to base 64.

So, if I understand this correctly, the corresponding PHP code would be:

```
base64_encode(sha1($sec-websocket-key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"));
```

However, this is not correct. It does not match the example shown on MDN (i.e. on MDN a value of `dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==` for the WebSocket key should return `s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=`, but using the PHP code that I have written, it returns `YjM3YTRmMmNjMDYyNGYxNjkwZjY0NjA2Y2YzODU5NDViMmJlYzRlYQ==`).

What have I done incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sha1()` function accepts an optional second boolean parameter which makes it return the raw SHA-1 digest in 20-character binary form rather than 40-character hexadecimal form (see [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)).

The WebSocket handshake requires the raw binary format. Thus, you need to add the second parameter to the `sha1()` function.

```
base64_encode(sha1($sec-websocket-key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11",true));
```